# Excel chart with markers -- how to automate the color, shape, and size of the markers

Tags: excel, charts

I have a chart with 90 series.  The first 87 series are plotted as lines with markers.  But since each series has just one data point, the 87 series show up as 87 dots represented by markers of different colors and shapes and sizes.  I would like to make these markers of only two shapes and colors, say blue squares and red triangles.  However, the only way I can do this is my manually clicking on each marker and changing its color, shape etc.  It is very cumbersome and every time we decide to change the color, I have to repeat the process.  Would really appreciate if someone could tell me how to automate this process.  I don't know Visual Basic but if it is just a short code, I will try my best to work with it -- I want to have the capability to say which series should look like blue squares and which like red triangles.

For the sake of completeness, the last three series are stacked area chart.

Data example of one series

```
Year  Series1
1990    N/A
1991    N/A
1992     5
1993    N/A
1994    N/A
```

Comment: Have you tried the macro recorder?

Comment: I tried the macro recorder but when I apply it using the short cut it fails most of the time giving errors

Comment: Any way to combine all the series you want as blue squares into one series (two columns in the worksheet), and red triangles into another?